# How to prevent an image from changing the height of a <img> element? HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, grid, height

I have a grid which I add grid-items to, then using the `thumbnail` class, I provide dimensions to the thumbnail class ( class) tag. The issue is when I add an image to the `<img>` tag, it changes the height dimension. I i don't want that to happen, instead I would like the  to stay with the dimensions I gave it.

So I have the following content box which I add to a grid:

```js
$('.content').append('<div class="grid-item"> <img class="thumbnail" src='+thumbnail+'><div class="details"><img class="profileImg" src='+profPic+'><span class="portalTitle">'+caption+'</span></div></div>');
```

I then have the following css for it:

```css
    .content {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr) );
      /* grid-template-columns:auto auto auto; */
      /* 10fr, 10fr, 10fr, 10fr; */
      /* auto auto auto; */
      /* background-color: #2196F3; */
      padding: 5px;
      margin-top: 25px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      margin-left: 250px;
      margin-bottom: 170px;
    }

    .grid-item {
      /* background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); */
      /* border: 1px solid grey; */
      padding: 0px;


      /* max-width: 440px;
      min-width: 439px; */


      /* 150px */
      /* font-size: 30px; */
      /* text-align: center; */
    }
    .thumbnail {
      /* background-color: black; */
      margin-right: 5px;
      width: 95%;
      /* height: 240px; */
      height: 70%;
      border-radius: 9px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* object-fit: cover; */

    .details {
      display: inline-flex;
      /* text-align: center; */
      /* display:block; */
      /* display:table-cell;
      vertical-align:middle; */

      /* background-color: grey; */
      margin-right: 5px;
      width: 95%;
      height: 80px;
    }
    .portalTitle {
      margin-top: 25px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      /* margin: auto; */
      /* line-height: 70px; */
      font: Arial;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight:500;
    }
    .profileImg {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

Here is some html:

```
<div class="content">
  <!-- <div class="grid-item">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="images/testImg.png">
    <div class="details">
      <img class="profileImg" src="images/testImg.png">
      <span class="portalTitle"> Shanghai, China night sounds</span>
    </div>
  </div> -->
</div>
```

**Update**: From what I gather, it seems that the height changes but the width stays the same. How do I fix this? The issue is that if I set a specific height instead of percentage, then the divs will stretch weirdly instead of dynamically scaling properly.

Image showing the issue (As you can see the div's have different heights when I want it to me more like youtube with consistent heights and widths)[image]

Comment: Do you want the thumbnail img to be 70% of grid-item's height, but without changing its h/w ratio? In that case, just remove the `width` property.

Comment: Can you create a snippet on jsFiddle for example? It would be helpful for us

Comment: @MrLister I had added an image to show but it was removed... Re added.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want you grid contents to be symmetrical but here the photos may have variable size or the txt content may vary.

for the images

```
.profileImg{

 min-width:5rem; 
 max-width:5rem;
 min-height:5rem; 
 max-height:5rem;

 }
```

apply similar css for thumbnail image

for the text you can set a limit you want to type and set a min-height and min-width for its div

personally I'll suggest you to use bootstrap row-col instead.It'll make your website more responsive as well.